# On CodeIgniter how to do simplest authentication / authorization

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, authorization

I have a `People` table and a `Roles` table. One Person can only be linked to One Role at any time. But One Role can house many People.

On my `People` table I have **Email** and **Password** as columns. How can I using these create the most basic of authentication / authorization setups? I have a CodeIgniter project, and on the `newscontroller`, I want user to:

1) Redirect Users to Login (if not logged in already)
2) If their roles aren't `Admin` or `Staff` then I'd like them to be re-directed to Home/Index, otherwise they can have fun creating news articles, deleting them ... etc

I want to keep it as simple as possible, so no Hashing / Salting of passwords .. etc (that all will come later). The tutorial I followed used a little cookie for persistence of authentication / logged in state. But it didn't work for me. :(

Can such a step be called "simple" ? If it is too much, then some good links would be useful. As the ones I googled were crap.

Thanks

Comment: on your people table you can insert another ID which is a role_id

Comment: I know, I have that already. My question is about how I can implement the simple authentication / authorization.

Comment: Do u need a little description of steps that needs to be followed ? And yes, such step is simple indeed

Comment: Yes please, and an example of the coookie would be nice. :)

Comment: use session and not cookie, have a look at this basic login system http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

Comment: maybe it helps you https://github.com/imagecms/ImageCMS/blob/master/application/modules/auth/auth.php

Comment: you must also look my libary Aauth  
https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my library to authentication but i didn't write a documentaton yet.

it has alot of fatures and im stil improving it.

in addition; i will relaese new version with extra futures soon.

Link : http://github.com/emreakay/Codeigniter-Aauth

Answer (score 2):

RBAC probably is not "simple", but there are only 2 roles(Admin or Staff) you can add flag "is_admin" in users table and operate it.
for autentification use session, store userID. thats enouth for get userdata and check logged user or not